# Yeoman Commands Issues Fatal Error

Tags: git, angularjs, ubuntu, yeoman

I already have npm and git installed on my Ubuntu machine.  When I started with Yeoman, I installed it with the following commands:

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-webapp
npm install -g generator-angular
```

Then I ran the following commands in my machine's terminal:

```
mkdir MyProject
cd MyProject
git init
yo angular
grunt serve
```

and receieved the following error:

> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt

I thought Yeoman would automate any grunt process.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong?  I can see that there is a `Gruntfile.js` in my main project's folder, so the problem is not obvious to me at the moment.

Any ideas?  Suggestions?

Comment: I ran the `npm install -g yo` command as instructed on the Yeoman.io site.  That should have installed grunt.  Is there a command I can run to check if grunt is installed?

Comment: Try running npm install in your MyProject folder.

Comment: Although `npm install -g yo` is automated to run `npm install` to grab dependencies, I guess something went wrong in the automation or interrupted its process.  I ran `npm install` manually and that resolved the issue.  I haven't seen this fatal error since.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget grunt-cli!

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: Yes, I had also run that previously, but it did not resolve the issue for me.  It seems that the website for Yoeman needs to be updated, and I think they have an issue created on Github regarding improving the documentation on Yeoman.io.

Improve Yoeman.io in 2014
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1245

Comment: I used yeoman as well to build my last angular project, but never had that error from the repo...

Comment: My machine settings must not have been correct and the machine must have been in an odd state.  I've submitted the suggestion to the yeoman developers to improve documenation on machine settings prior to running the 'yo angular' command.